# Graph API - why am I receiving a deprecation error? (Error 12)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to leverage the Graph API for a BI report, but when I use

```
{page_ID}/conversations
```

I receive this error:

```
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) This endpoint is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 12,
```

I'm testing in Graph API explorer, and I have the required access tokens.  I can't determine what the issue is based on all the documentation I've reviewed.

Comment: it says that this endpoint is deprecated and is not working when you call graphapi versions 2.4 and higher.
What is the full url you are trying to access ?

Comment: graph.facebook.com/v2.10/{page_id}/Conversations is the URL I am using in the BI tool.  This syntax works just fine for other elements, like "Insights".

For Graph API Explorer, the developer test tool, it's just GET /v2.10/{page_id}/Conversations.  Documentation says Conversations ID has been deprecated, but it does not suggest that the above syntax should no longer work.